# Ajax returning an empty array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get some data however AJAX is just returning empty array.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url:"user_profile_upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { data : 'sss'},
            contentType:false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

user_profile_upload.php PHP:

```
die(print_r($_POST,true));
```

Comment: post the code of "user_profile_upload.php"

Comment: Remove `processData: false` so that the data you plan to send is encoded properly. Why did you set it anyway?

Comment: Don't use `print_r` for printing data. Use `json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: tried both but it hasn't worked

Comment: Array ( ) this is what I get back from the ajax

Comment: Also get rid of `contentType: false`. Those two options are used when the data is a `FormData` object.

Comment: You don't need `cache: false`, because `POST` requests are never cached.

Comment: Tried that too, still not working

Comment: If you send your php file directly by going to that url and just statically giving post at the top does it function?

Answer (score -1):

**user_profile_upload.php** use echo

```
<?php
  //echo $_POST; //return array, response in javascript file
  echo $_POST['data'];
?>
```

**AJAX** remove this

```
processData:false, 
contentType:false
```